# Dynamic QUERY Function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet connected to a Google Form. I am gathering information about several teams, and I want to display information about each specific team.

Rather than creating 27 separate sheets for each team, I thought about creating a **dynamic sheet** that would ask for the team number (each team has its own number, like 6544), then query that team. Here's how it works:

Team Number: **|** 6544 (this is cell B1)

Then, the query code looks like this:

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!B2:G, "SELECT * WHERE C = " + B1 "")
```

I thought I could concatenate the value from B1 (the team number the user entered) into the string query, so it would look like this:

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!B2:G, "SELECT * WHERE C = 6544")
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. I get `#ERROR!` in the cell, then when I hover over it, it reads `Formula parse error.`

Any ideas what went wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. To concatenate the strings, I need to use the `&` operator, not addition like in JavaScript or Java.

So the script looks like this:

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!B2:G, "SELECT * WHERE C = " & B1)
```

It works now!

Comment: Keep in mind that `CONCAT` could've worked too. The function would have looked like this:

`=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!B2:G, CONCAT("SELECT * WHERE C = ", B1))`

This, however, is longer, so I simply used the `&` operator. They both work the same, though.